# Accidently wiped out all data. Now I can't restore it.

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I accidently wiped out all data on the device (no backup). Now I'm in TWRP and when I select "Restore", there is no package to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't had this issue, and I'm not experienced much.

If you plugged it into your computer, opened KFU (not sure if it'd detect it), you can download the latest stock ROM. Then maybe all you'd have to do is push it onto the SDcard through ADB? and then reload TWRP (or something to refresh the list) and it'd appear, and then you could flash it?

Not sure if that'd work. Again, not an experienced person with this, but maybe you can figure something out with my idea. :P

Comment: I did it!!!!!!!!! :D I'm so scared it becomes a brick. :)) Now everything's ok. I understood how TWRP works!
http://www.jayceooi.com/2011/12/28/how-to-restore-stock-software-on-kindle-fire-video/

Comment: Next time, take a quick back up before moving forward. Even then, if you were to brick your Kindle, there are a few known methods of unbricking it.